# SWT: drawing an image that is updated frequently

Tags: java, image, swt

I'm working on an SWT application that has a high data rate (about 10hz). When I get new data, I need to redraw the entire image. This is how it currently looks:

```
public class ImageRenderer implements PaintListener
{
    private final ImageData _ImageData;

    public ImageRenderer(int pWidth, int pHeight, PaletteData pPalet, int pImageDepth)
    {
        _ImageData = new ImageData(pWidth, pHeight, pPalet, pImageDepth);
    } 

    public void updateData(byte [] pRaster)   
    {
        _ImageData.data = pRaster;
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
            {
                  public void run()
                  {
                      redraw();
                  }

            });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent pEvent)
    {
        Image image = new Image(pEvent.gc.getDevice(), imageData);
        pEvent.gc.setAdvanced(true);
        pEvent.gc.setAntialias(SWT.OFF);
        pEvent.gc.drawImage(
            image,0,0,imageData.width,imageData.height,
            0,0,imageData.width, imageData.height);
        image.dispose();
    }

}
```

I'm currently running on Fedora 9. When this code executes, I see the JVM's CPU as well as X's CPU spike. When I hooked into the JVM with visual VM, I saw the following:

org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gdk_pixbuf_render_to_drawable[native] (96%)

I suspect that this might be linked to the number of images I'm creating. When I've written similar applications in AWT-Swing, I create a BufferedImage, update the raster and call repaint. The image is created once and the image is easily drawn.

Ideally I'd like to do something similar. I was hoping there would be a way to draw the contents of the ImageData without having to create an image each time. If I offload the creation of the image, off of the display thread, I see the same behavior.

I thought about using the SWT_AWT bridge to create a panel that uses the BufferedImage approach mentioned above. I'm not sure if the bridge is doing a conversion back to an Image under the covers, in which case I'm not sure that solution would solve anything.

Comment: I just wrote a proof of concept that uses the SWT_AWT bridge to add a JPanel with a custom paintComponent method and I saw drastic improvement, with respect to CPU utilization on the JVM and X. If I don't hear anything else, this is going to be the approach I'm going with.